# Redirect after all nested AJAX requests are successful

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am currently working on feature that uses AJAX but in this case it uses multiple *optional* nested ajax requests. I cant seem to figure out the best approach to perform a redirect after the ajax requests are successful. So the idea is to run the main ajax request and in the success function call other ajax functions. Please bear in mind that the nested ajax requests are optional.

```
        $.ajax
            ({
                 type: "POST",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 data: "{'articleName':'" + webName + "', 'title':'" + titleContent + "', 'body':'" + content + "', 'categoryID':'" + $('.js-category-select').val() + "'}",
                 dataType: "json",
                 url: "/internal-service/service.asmx/EditBlogPost",
                                success: (function (data)
                                {
                                    var returnVal = data.d;

                                    //Is there extensions
                                    if ($("[data-blog-type-id]").length > 0)
                                    {
                                        var extensionAry = [];

                                        $("[data-blog-type-id]").each(function ()
                                        {
                                            if ($(this).val() != "")
                                            {
                                                extensionAry.push($(this).attr("data-f-name") + "|" + $(this).val());
                                            }
                                        });

                                        //Must be bookReview field extensions
                                        //send array (if has value)
                                        if (extensionAry.length > 0)
                                        {
                                            $.ajax
                                                ({
                                                    type: "POST",
                                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                                    data: JSON.stringify({ articleWebname: webName, extensionAry: extensionAry }),
                                                    dataType: "json",
                                                    url: "/internal-service/service.asmx/EditBlogExtensions",
                                                    success: (function (data)
                                                    {
                                                       alert(data.d);
                                                    }),
                                                    error: (function ()
                                                    {
                                                        //error
                                                        alert("ERROR!");
                                                    })
                                                });
                                        }

                                    }

                                    //Has Rating extension
                                    if ($(".js-rating").length > 0)
                                    {
                                        var ratingVal = $(".js-rating").val();
                                        $.ajax
                                            ({
                                                type: "POST",
                                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                                data: JSON.stringify({ articleWebname: webName, rating: ratingVal }),
                                                dataType: "json",
                                                url: "/internal-service/service.asmx/EditBlogRating",
                                                success: (function (data)
                                                {
                                                    alert(data.d);
                                                }),
                                                error: (function () {
                                                    //error
                                                    alert("ERROR!");
                                                })
                                            });
                                    }

                                    if (returnVal != "Error updating blog post")
                                    {
                                        //Return the path of the article just in case the title has been changed. page uses the title to locate the article on the server
                                        alert(returnVal + " Good job!");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        alert(returnVal);
                                    }
                                }),
                                error: (function () {
                                    //error
                                    alert("ERROR!");
                                })
                            });
```

In the backend (C#) it's a pluggable system where as I can create an application and then I can install a blog which in turn has extensions of different blog types. Also the blog system can have additional plugins I.E rating plugin.

The AJAX seems worrying and may suffer from scalability issues. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

So the question is, IF the optional nested AJAX requests have been called, how do I wait for them to complete and then redirect (will redirect to the same page)?

Comment: Simplify the code using jQuery promises.

Break your code into separate functions per load, that each return their Ajax promise.

You can then chain the calls with `then` or run them in parallel with `$.when`. To pass complex results use `$.Deferred()` to create a specific promise that can be resolved with your own additional data.

Comment: Agreed. Such deep nesting is unattractive and unwieldy to maintain. Chaining promises together is much better in both regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify the code using jQuery promises.

Break your code into separate functions per load, that each return their Ajax promise.

e.g.

```
    function PostBlah() {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{'articleName':'" + webName + "', 'title':'" + titleContent + "', 'body':'" + content + "', 'categoryID':'" + $('.js-category-select').val() + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/internal-service/service.asmx/EditBlogPost"
        });
    }
```

You can then chain the calls with `then` or `done` or run them in parallel with `$.when`.

```
     postBlah().then(function(dataFromPostBlah){
         step2(dataFromPostBlah).then(function(dataFromStep2){
             // etc
         });
     });
```

This will keep the top-level code much simpler. Look into jQuery promises for more details.

To pass complex results use `$.Deferred()` to create a specific promise that can be resolved with your own additional data.

e.g.

```
function DoMore(parameter){
    var def = $.Deferred();
    // Do some stuff asynchronously
        // When you get a result back later - resolve the promise
        def.resolve(myComplicatedData);
    // return a promise to return some complicated data later
    return def.promise();
}
```

Here is a generic JSFiddle promise testbed I put together to demonstrate the basic promise logic (and let you play with options):

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/nexpe8pt/2/

Comment: Fantastic answer! But I'm slightly struggling to understand the syntax. Could you elaborate on the middle tier code snippet? So if I have three functions: EditBlogPost(), EditBlogExtensions() and EditBlogRating() how would that be written in your snippet? Also could I check if the first passes, then run the rest? The first request is vital. I return a "Success" message from the backend. Sorry struggling to understand the syntax. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I will update tomorrow (time zones) with a mockup. Promises have provision for done & fail chaining. Very flexible.

Comment: Much appreciated! Luck forward to it! jQuery API documentation is not filling the gap in knowledge.

Comment: @Tez Wingfield: Answer updated with a little JSFiddle testbed, so you can play with jQuery promises in a safe environment :)

Comment: Apologies for the delay in reply. Absolutely amazing, thank you. Just need to try figure syntax to get it to work with ajax requests. Again thank you.